# Nethermind conditions

Tags: clients

I'm using nethermind client.

The client is running on VM with using VMM of Synology NAS(model:ds918+).
The NAS is installed 14GB HDD, 1TB read/write SSD caches, 4core cpu(Intel Celeron J3455).
OS on VM is ubuntu server 20.04.

However, it seems to be too slow syncing.
See the following screen shots.

[image: screen shot 1]
[image: screen shot 2]

I'm not familiar with nethermind console messages, but are the number 0kB/s - 13kB/s on console normal?
I didn't any change configs.

When I was using Geth on the same machine(OS on VM is ubuntu desktop 18.04), it was syncing normally.
So I think the machine spec meets requirement.

Please let me know if anyone knows the cause. It's also a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have only found your question now so obviously the Nethermind code changed a lot since the time the question was asked.

Your diagnostic field shows very long IO access times which may be caused by:

- too slow IO (Nethermind requires slightly faster IO to deal with the number of concurrent IO access of the fast sync(
- the node has been restarted many times during the sync